# Gulp useref error

Tags: build, gulp, twig, symfony-3.4

I am trying to use gulp useref to combine js files.

Here is the gulp task:

```
gulp.task('useref', function () {
   return gulp.src('templates/base.html.twig')
   .pipe(useref(
   {
      transformPath: (filePath) => {
        return filePath.replace('/templates', '')
      }
    }
 ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'));
});
```

and in base.html.twig i have:

```
<!-- build:js web/js/combined.js -->
            <script src="{{asset('js/profile/edit/js-script.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
```

So when I ttry to run gulp useref task I have this error:
Error: File not found with singular glob: /var/www/html/project/templates/js/profile/edit/js-script.js (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)

Now it creates web/js folder inside web/js that are allready there and also it create base.html.twig inside.

Hope some one can help me with this.

Comment: OK I have fixed this. but now it creates duplicate base.html.twig and inside of it it combine the js files.

Any help?

Comment: Now I even fix this with editing this line 
<!-- build:js web/js/combined.js -->
to
<!-- build:js /combined.js -->

But it still copy base.html.twig...